# Photoshop Hue Change Color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs6, tiles

I am doing tilemapping for a game. I originally went with a bright, vivid style but now want to tone it down into a more realistic style.

I spent a lot of time making a nice grass tile, but as you can see, it clearly doesn't match the darker colors in the tree that I'm going for:

[image]

Following [this tutorial on hues](http://www.sitepoint.com/change-colors-in-photoshop-with-the-hue-blend-mode/), instead of redoing the grass tile, I decided to just change the hue to match. I selected the tree's base dark green color to paint over the grass, but it's coming out as an ugly olive color:

[image]

Clearly I am doing something wrong here. Which is the best way to change the grass coloring such that I retain the texturing?

---

Edit: I found going to Image -> Adjustments -> Hue/Saturation is a good way to go... it allows you to play with Hue, Saturation & Lightness all within the same control panel until you get what you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have a color issue, but a brightness issue. The grass looks like it could be a bright sunny day. The tree appears more dusk colored.

Comment: @DA01 Good point. For a game that probably won't have change of time or different weather, what's a good average to go with?

Comment: I think it depends entirely on the game...both the game play and the aesthetic you are after.

Comment: I think your edited version feels much better as a pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to experiment with modes and opacity to get where you want to go...

[image]

I, personally, would probably opt for the **Color** blending mode above Hue. Then simply adjust the opacity of the layer until you're happy.