# How can I change this picture to orange color in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have following image in blue color, which I need to change to orange keeping the that style also.

I tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RBAeCtFOBo, but it gives very dull orange color ( versions of #ffa500).

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoshop Hue Change Color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/photoshop-hue-change-color)

Answer (score 2):

Use an adjustment layer - Hue/Saturation.

I chose on this to use 'Colorize' which helps flatten the colour output, otherwise you get greenish or reddish tinges in the yellow/orange. I pushed Saturation to give it a bit of punch, though Vibrancy may work too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do it.  Here's one method which uses a Black & White adjustment layer, and a Color Fill adjustment layer (filled orange) with the blending mode set to *Vivid Light*.

[image]